# Why does my game look different on my mobile device than in the editor?

Tags: rendering, lighting, unreal-4, mobile

I am new to Unreal Engine. My game in mobile looks totally different than in Unreal Engine editor.

**In Editor:**[image]

**In Mobile:**[image]

Is this a symptom of something obvious? How can I make it so that what I'll see in the editor will be the same thing that I'll see on my mobile device?

Comment: Hi Mokshith, is it possible to provide more information about what your expected result is? Currently the question is rather unclear.

Comment: It would help if you included the steps you took to build this visual - we can't necessarily tell from a screenshot what materials / settings / etc. you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably because your project is using a post processing effect that mobile either doesn't support or an asset is missing. When I was using UE4 usually if there is something wrong with materials when exporting to mobile the console would tell me.

This guy had a similar issue:
https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/561835/index.html